# como funcionan los rangos en reportlab en la creacion de un pdf en python

Tags: python, reportlab

podrian explicarme como es que funcionan los rangos que se le colocan a los estylos

```
table.setStyle([('VALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'TOP'),
                    ('LINEABOVE', (1, 0), (1, 0), 1, colors.black),
                    ('LINEABOVE', (3, 0), (3, 0), 1, colors.black)])
```

Comment: Parece que [aqui](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/09/21/reportlab-tables-creating-tables-in-pdfs-with-python/) lo explican con bastante detalle, pues al parecer la documentación de reportlab no es demasiado buena.

Comment: ya lo leí y aun asi es confuso, pordrias ayudarme, siguiendo este ejemplo

Comment: @abulafia el link está roto.

Comment: @MonsieurGalois Hay una copia en [wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20161121080042/https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/09/21/reportlab-tables-creating-tables-in-pdfs-with-python/)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, lo revisaré ahora mismo.